# How can I use External Secrets Operator to copy Kubernetes secrets from one namespace to another?

Tags: external-secrets-operator

I'm using External Secrets Operator to copy secrets from external providers into Kubernetes secrets, and it works great for that.

Now I'd like to copy (& synchronize) a secret from one Kubernetes namespace, into another (or potentially, many).

The problem is, I can't figure out how to configure the ClusterSecretStore and ExternalSecret to do this. I need to be able to specify the origin namespace of the secret in ExternalSecret, but I can't find anywhere in the API spec on how to do this.

I can reference a SecretStore in the same namespace as the ExternalSecret, if I wanted to access secrets in the current namespace. And I can reference a ClusterSecretStore, so that I can use the same Store from any namespace, which sounds good at first... but in the ExternalSecret, I can't find any configuration that allows me to configure "use ClusterSecretStore, and find X secret in Y namespace".

Am I going crazy?? Can anyone point me to the right configuration?

I deployed a ClusterSecretStore for Kubernetes, and it has validated.

I look for the ExternalSecretStore API reference, and I can't find a way (in `data` or `dataFrom` sections) to reference a specific namespace for a specific secret. I expected there to be some way to specify the namespace.

Comment: You can go with Service Account or third party operator.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  You used the kubernetes flag which, if you read the description, says "KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here."

Comment: @possum thanks I have removed the kubernetes flag. Pretty weird restriction on such a generic flag but oh well.

Comment: @possum this reads like a software development question to me.

Answer (score 0):

The [ESO - External Secrets Operator](https://external-secrets.io/v0.4.4/) integrates external secret manager to directly use the stored secret to k8s secret.

Based on the docs the [`ClusterSecretStore`](https://external-secrets.io/v0.4.4/api-clustersecretstore/) shall be the cluster scope level of [`SecretStore`](https://external-secrets.io/v0.4.4/api-secretstore/) wherein [`ExternalSecret`](https://external-secrets.io/v0.4.4/api-externalsecret/) fetches data on the the secret store.

For you to be able to use the same secret in different namespaces thus "**replicating same secret**" on different namespace inside the cluster, `ExternalSecret` should be configured properly.

On the part of the yaml, you should look on the following spec to properly point the `SecretStoreRef` to the `ExternalSecret`:

```
spec:

  # SecretStoreRef defines which SecretStore to use when fetching the secret data
  secretStoreRef:
    name: secret-store-name
    kind: SecretStore  # or ClusterSecretStore

  # RefreshInterval is the amount of time before the values reading again from the SecretStore provider
  # Valid time units are "ns", "us" (or "µs"), "ms", "s", "m", "h" (from time.ParseDuration)
  # May be set to zero to fetch and create it once
  refreshInterval: "1h"

  # the target describes the secret that shall be created
  # there can only be one target per ExternalSecret
  target:

    # The secret name of the resource
    # Defaults to .metadata.name of the ExternalSecret
    # It is immutable
    name: my-secret
```

Alternatively, you can use [Reflector](https://github.com/emberstack/kubernetes-reflector) as add on to your cluster

Comment: can an ExternalSecret in namespace "app-a" use a SecretStore that only exists in namespace "app-b" ?